# Summing up a list in a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to sum up the points inside a For loop.
As you can see in my code, the number of elements (entries) in "points" is different.
Can someone help me to implement this pytonically?

student1 = {'name': 'Hans', 'points': [285, 210, 135, 100, 300]}
student2 = {'name': 'Peter', 'points': [65, 56, 48]}

students = [student1, student2]

for stud in students:
sumpoints = stud['points'][0]+stud['points'][1]+stud['points'][2]

print(sumpoints)]

The print output should look like this:

```
Hans: 1030
Peter: 169
```

That's why I put it in a for loop.

Comment: Hint: use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sum) function

Comment: Are there restrictions to the solution like: (a) only use for-loop, (b) don't use external modules, (c) it must be pythonic - which can contradict a for-loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum()` will sum of iterable of numbers regardless the numbers of element.

You can use dict comprehension to achieve what you need:

**EDIT: Changes variable name in dict comprehension for better readability**

```
student1 = {'name': 'Hans', 'points': [285, 210, 135, 100, 300]}
student2 = {'name': 'Peter', 'points': [65, 56, 48]}

students = [student1, student2]

sumpoints = {student['name']: sum(student['points']) for student in students}
print(sumpoints)
for key, val in sumpoints.items(): print(f'{key}: {val}')

# {'Hans': 1030, 'Peter': 169}
# Hans: 1030
# Peter: 169
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What you have

Your current code prints:

```
169
```

Explain your code and intentions by comments:

```
student1 = {'name': 'Hans', 'points': [285, 210, 135, 100, 300]}
student2 = {'name': 'Peter', 'points': [65, 56, 48]}

students = [student1, student2]

# Print a line for each student with his name and the sum of his/her points.
# Example:
# Hans: 1030
# Peter: 169
for stud in students:
    sumpoints = stud['points'][0]+stud['points'][1]+stud['points'][2]  # this will not adjust for varying list-length

print(sumpoints)  # this is outside the for-loop, it only prints the sum of the last student
```

#### What is missing?

- a line printed per student (inside the loop)
- the name of the student at the beginning of the printed
- the sum per student should summarize all points not only the first 3

```
for stud in students:
    # following debug prints can be removed when working correctly
    print(stud['name'])  # see how each student is iterated - a new line
    print(stud['points'])  # see the list varies (length and elements)
    # the demo can be completed by you
    stud_sum = sum([0,1,2]) # sum-function adjusts for varying list-length, it sums up all elements - here a demo list
    print("Name" + ":" +  str(stud_sum))  # inside the for-loop, to print for each student - the name is just a demo
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the total points of all students, it'll look something like this:

```
sumpoints = 0
for stud in students:
    sumpoints += sum(stud['points'])
```

Comment: Interesting solution to sum-up all points of all students as grand-total. Your "if you want" already indicates that we are not sure what was asked for. First clarify using comments, then answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `sum` function will sum a list without you specifying a size and a list comprehension will apply that to each student.

```
student1 = {'name': 'Hans', 'points': [285, 210, 135, 100, 300]}
student2 = {'name': 'Peter', 'points': [65, 56, 48]}

students = [student1, student2]

sumpoints = [sum(student['points']) for student in students]
print(sumpoints)
```

Output is a sum per student

```
[1030, 169]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
this is not quite what I wanted, I want it to be output as follows:

Hans: 1030
Peter: 169

That's why I put it in a for loop.

Comment: You are elaborating on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990312/summing-up-a-list-in-a-dictionary#comment130642857_73990312) which was intended as hint. Besides teaching basic loops and `+` operators/assignments before advanced concepts like list-comprehension and `sum()` - are we already sure, what is expected and what are the restrictions?